# Refresh gives blank page php

Tags: php, refresh

I used the function header() in a  code block to refresh the page after the user writes and submits an input. The code stores the inputs in variables and then refreshes the page. When I ran it the page refreshed but gave a white blank page with no o/p at all

Here's the refreshment code

```
header("refresh:0");
exit();
```

Any help?

Comment: I think there is a problem with your other code because this piece of code is fine. can you post your full code?

Comment: It's depend on your coded that were executed before `exit(0)`.
`exit(0)` will stop running your project, I prefer delete it.

Comment: use: ` echo '<script type="text/javascript">','window.location.reload();','</script>';`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the correct code.
To redirect to same page,

```
header( "Refresh:0");
```

To redirect to another page,

```
header("Refresh:0; url=yourPage.php");
```

Comment: still nothing to show :(

Comment: remove the exit() maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect user to same page you could simply use

```
header("Location: yourfile.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found 2 Ways to refresh a PHP content :

**1.Using HTML META :**

```
echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>"); //Refresh by HTTP META
```

**2.Using PHP REFRESH RATE :**

```
//Where 0 is an example of time Delay you can use 5 for 5 seconds for example !
$delay=0; 
header("Refresh: $delay; url=yourURL.php");
```